# I need help organizing/planning a C# Tic Tac Toe Application

Tags: c#, data-structures

I'm a University Student who has experience in C++ and is new to C#.  I wanted some feedback about how to approach building a C# Form application for a 5x5 Tic Tac Toe Game.

The specifics of the program require that a user enters a time for the player to make a move choice.  Then the player selects whether they or the computer will go first.  Then the player clicks a start button for the game to commence.

So far I figured I'd created a 'Move' class with a X and Y Coordinate representing a location on a game grid, and a 'Player' class that contains a list of 'Move' objects that they have made in the game.  I was planning on adding a grid of clickable labels that would add a move to the players list of moves.  As for the AI, I think it would be pretty easy to create an algorithm to block the human player from completing a row, but I'm not sure what data structure would be most efficient for this. Perhaps I'm thinking about it all wrong to begin with.

Any thoughts?

Comment: There are various articles are available on internet, you can check this resources too: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/432297/Tic-Tac-Toe-Game-Programming-Using-Csharp http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/647947/Create-Tic-Tac-Toe-Game

Comment: What kind of application are you building? Windows Form, WPF or web based?

Comment: This is a Form application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the UI, I will use a 5 * 5 `TableLayoutControl` with a `Button` in each cell. You can set the `FlatStyle` for these button to `Flat` for the look.

Now, as far as maintaining a model is concerned, I will just have a single class to represent players. Something like this:

```
class Player : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        List<Point> _selectedCells = new List<Point>();

        public List<Point> SelectedCells
        {
            get
            {
                return _selectedCells;
            }
            set
            {
                if (value != _selectedCells)
                {
                    _selectedCells = value;
                    RaisePropertyChange(new PropertyChangedEventArgs("SelectedCells"));
                }
            }
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        protected void RaisePropertyChange(PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, e);
            }
        }
    }
```

Now, there will be 2 instances of this class. One for human and one for computer. On button click, you can set `SelectedCells` property. Now, changing this property will raise `PropertyChanged` event. a handler can be placed that checks for the victory.

If user has not won yet, generate computer move and set same property on computer instance. Again it will check for victory.

As and when a user wins, you can display appropriate message. You can add a string property `Name` to `Player` class to ease the victory message display mechanism.

Comment: I'm not following the logic of choosing points for your list type.  Sorry if this is obvious, We're being thrown in the deep end here and I don't have a lot of user interface/C# experience.

Comment: That is coordinates of TableLayoutCell in which button belongs.